# If string is name of one of column, take rows including this string, if not remove row with python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two files. First one looks like this:

| A | B | C | D | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.002 | 0.25 | 1.25 | 2.45 | 3.54 |
| 0.15 | 0.45 | 2.35 | 0.48 | 4.57 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

and the second one :

| letter | ID |
| --- | --- |
| A | 12 |
| T | 12 |
| C | 23 |
| D, J | 15 |
| K | 45 |
| M, A, C | 35 |

If one of column name of first file does not appear in the second file then remove it from second file, like this:

| letter | ID |
| --- | --- |
| A | 12 |
| C | 23 |
| D | 15 |
| A, C | 35 |

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `loc` to filter your df2 based on df1's columns:

```
>>> df2.loc[df2.letter.isin(list(df1))]

  letter  ID
0      A  12
2      C  23
```

`list(df1)` will return df1's columns as a list which can be passed into `isin` which is used on the 'letter' column in df2.

---

Given your edits, you can use the following approach:

```
df2_exp = df2.assign(g=df2.groupby('letter').ngroup(),
           letter=df2.letter.str.split(',')
           ).explode('letter')

df2_exp.loc[
    df2_exp.letter.str.strip().isin(list(df1)
                                    )
    ].groupby('g').agg({'ID':'first','letter':lambda letter: ','.join(letter)
                        }).reset_index(drop=True)
```

prints:

```
   ID letter
0  12      A
1  23      C
2  15      D
3  35   A, C
```

Comment: I just edit my question. Could you please look again? @sophocles

Comment: Just did, please have a look.